# Advanced filtering of usernames in search

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-apps-email

The school I attend uses Google Apps for mail; using a set system for all student email addresses. The system is similar to this example: `11A[surname and initial]@domain.org`.

I would like a way to set a filter or label for the 11A group, the 11B group and so on. Anything after the group '11x' can be left - it just needs to show all emails from users with that prefix. If case sensitivity matters, I am specifically trying to filter emails with the prefix `11n`.

Is there a way to use the 'from operator' to list all emails from users with the `11A` (for example) section of the email address - allowing me to find all emails sent from students in the same assigned group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might just start with a search of

```
from:"11A"
```

which would include all email address with that exact phrase, you could then use NOT filters to limit any extra junk coming in.

Otherwise you'll probably need REGEX (not supported in search/filter but can get the same results using Google Docs and a sheet someone made just for this, http://www.labnol.org/internet/advanced-gmail-search/21623/.  After that, this REGEX

```
^11A.*@domain.org
```

should at least get you started.

Comment: Hi, for some reason the `from:"11A"` search does not return any results (even though I've got lots of emails with that prefix) and the Google Docs Regex sheet just stays on the "Now scanning your Gmail mailbox. Please wait.." popup. I don't know if there's another way to filter in this way. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've awarded you the bounty for the detailed answer, although I have found another solution: although time consuming I've just specified all the email addresses with that prefix. Thanks again!